# Angular web app converted to capacitor iOS app doesn't render menu buttons

Tags: ios, angular, capacitor

I am trying to make an ios app from an angular web app. I don't get any errors during build or sync. The menu items show up correctly in the web app but in the ios emulated app they don't. I don't have much knowledge in xcode or mobile app development. How do I edit the capacitor app what should I do? any suggestions? I tried researching but found no answer to my question. If you need any additional files or info to answer just ask. Thanks

***home.component.html***

```
<div
  class="home-container centered -v"
  [style]="{ height: navbar.visible ? 'calc(100% - 5vh)' : '100%' }"
>
  <h1 i18n>Welcome!</h1>
  <h3 i18n>Where to next?</h3>

  <div class="grid centered -h">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
      <div
        *ngIf="item?.visible"
        [routerLink]="item.routerLink"
        class="card col-5 lg:col-3 centered -v"
      >
        <i [class]="item.icon"></i>

        <h3>
          {{ item.label }}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

***home.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core'
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs'
import { NavbarService } from 'src/app/common/components/navbar/navbar.service'
import { MobileService } from 'src/app/shared/services/extras/mobile.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  menuItems: any[]

  constructor(
    public navbar: NavbarService,
    private mobile: MobileService

  ) {
    if (this.mobile.isMobile) this.navbar.visible = false

    this.Init()
  }

  async Init() {
    await lastValueFrom(this.navbar._initDone, { defaultValue: '' })

    this.menuItems = this.navbar.menuItems
      .slice(1)
      .flatMap((item) =>
        item.items ? item.items : item.routerLink ? item : null
      )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.navbar.visible = true
  }
}
```

**Web app:**
[image: Web App]
**IOS app:**
[image: Web App]